# Generic where, cast object to interface

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core

I've got problem with code example attached below.
I want a limit generic class with interface because I would like use a specific method provided by cless which implement this interface.In my opinion this code should works, but complier throws error CS1503(Cannot convert).Why?

```
namespace Generics
{
    public interface Ibar
    {
    }

    public class foo : Ibar
    {
    }

    public class Demo<T> where T : Ibar
    {
    }

    public class testClass
    {
        public void makeSth(Demo<Ibar> ss)
        {

        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            Demo<foo> test = new Demo<foo>();

            testClass testclass = new testClass();

            testclass.makeSth(test); //what?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well yes, a `Demo<foo>` isn't convertible to a `Demo<IBar>`. Just like a `List<Stream>` isn't a `List<IDisposable>`.

Comment: `Demo<foo>` is not `Demo<Ibar>`. use [Covariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance).

Comment: Classes are invariant in C#, so `Demo<foo>` is a completely different type than `Demo<Ibar>` and an instance of `Demo<foo>` is therefor not assignable to a variable (or parameter) of type `Demo<Ibar>`.